# date time filter in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have a report to be generated every hour from a sql query.
The request here is to generate data from yesterday's  night 8.00 pm till
today's 12 pm noon . I am using the below query but not getting correct data:

```
select * from roster_report where job_start > TRUNC(SYSDATE-1) + 20/24 ;
```

Suppose today's date is 29th April, the report generated on 29th april 11:15 pm is showing data of 29th april 8:00 pm to 11:15 pm  correctly.
the data gets incorrect after 00:00 am where it fetches data of 29th april itself and not 30th april.

The query will be used after every hour to generate report.
I am running this in oracle sql developer.

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Explain what "not getting correct data" means.  Sample data and desired results would help.  Also, is 12pm intended to mean midnight (which I think is what you want) or noon?

Comment: Looks like Oracle.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - I have answered your questions I believe

Comment: You can use Between function to get the range time

Answer (score 0):

For previous day 8 PM

```
SELECT to_char(trunc(SYSDATE -1) + 20/24,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss AM') FROM dual;
```

For Today's 12 PM

```
SELECT to_char(trunc(SYSDATE) + 12/24,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss AM') FROM dual;
```

Sample Query

```
WITH DATA AS
( SELECT 'text' col, SYSDATE create_date FROM dual
  )
select *
from tw_logtable
where tw_logtable.created_datetime
BETWEEN (TRUNC(sysdate -1) + 20/24) AND (TRUNC(sysdate) + 12/24)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WHERE 
    job_start >= ( TRUNC(SYSDATE-1) + INTERVAL '20' HOUR ) 
AND job_start <= ( TRUNC(SYSDATE)   + INTERVAL '12' HOUR  )
```

You could just use `>` or `<` if that suits your requirement. `BETWEEN` can also be used for simplicity if all you want is inclusive range.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two ways:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ROSTER_REPORT 
 WHERE JOB_START BETWEEN (TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) + 20/24) 
                     AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 12/24 ;
```

or

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ROSTER_REPORT 
 WHERE JOB_START BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1,'DD/MM/RRRR')||' 20:00','DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI') 
                     AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE  ,'DD/MM/RRRR')||' 12:00','DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI');
```